# Unique Generation of 14 Digits (numbers)

Tags: api, random, key, java

I need the best algorithm or API to generate 14 digits that are uniquely identified with a possibility reaching 0 to have duplicates. The pattern of generation is about 12 times in the year with bulk of 10 million, hence the total will be 120 million record uniquely identified.

Comment: "possibility reaching 0 to have duplicates" that's not random then; as a random generator will have a 1 in <rand range> of returning any number ... meaning that with a range of 500million, for the last number you'd have a 120 / 500 chance of a duplicate for that one number

Comment: @saka1029 thanks man but no i need 14 digits

Comment: @UKMonkey i agree with you its not random, do you know any algorithm for generating unique 14 digits.

Comment: How about randomly generating 1 digit at a time?  Assuming that you're going for 0-9 for all digits, you should get a pretty reasonable distribution.  If you really need them to be unique, as StephenC says, you need to record them and check them.

Answer (score 0):

If you chose numbers randomly from a fixed range of integers, then the probability of duplicates is not zero.

If you want numbers that are hard to guess and unique then you need:

- a good random number generator, and
- a database (or similar) to hold all of the numbers you have previously generated.

The algorithm (pseudo-code) is:

```
while (true) {
    number = generate();
    if (!lookupInDatabase(number)) {
        recordInDatabase(number);
        return number;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but as i mentioned before there is a huge number of records and i do not want each time i generate a number to check if it exist over more than 120 million record.

Comment: Have you heard of indexes?  You don't need to check 120 million records each time.